# Is there a size limit to how many members or the type types of variables a structure may contain?

Tags: c, structure

I ran into some weird issues (at compile time) with my embedded C code when I increased the size of the array from size [2] to [27] which contained structured metadata. So it is obvious that this is a nested structured style program and NOT my original work!
I remember in assembly code instructions, there used to be a JMP FAR, JMP NEAR/SHORT.. Is there any such limitations in structures (obviously there is no jump in structures). Could there be a condition that the compiler cannot assign a contiguous memory block for a structure because there is a limit to it and fails during compilation.
SOME CLUE: The fix as i recall was to move the member (array member)from **original structure** to another **nested structure**. That's the reason why i deduced that there maybe a limitation.

```
//STRUCTURES
typedef UINT8 P_Name_t[5];
typedef UINT8 ChipSN_t[3]; 

typedef struct                   
{  
   ChipSN_t  ChipSN; 
   <other members>   
} ChipIdent_t;


typedef struct Data_t              
{ 
   ChipIdent_t      ReadOnlyMemID;
    <other members>   
} Data_t;


typedef struct                
{
   P_Name_t NameOfPart;   
   <other members>
} Log_t;

Data_t     Data_Src;

typedef struct
{
   P_Name_t       NameOfPart;           
   ChipSN_t       ChipSN;   
}PartNum_ID_t;


typedef struct
{
   PartNum_ID_t PN_ChipID[27];
   <other members>; 
}
```

Comment: There are limits, but nothing this small.  The problem is not that 27 bytes is "too big", it's probably something else (like maybe padding you're not accounting for).

Comment: What are your issues? Do you have a compile error or a runtime error? There isn't enough code here to form any sort of answer.

Comment: I think it would help if you edited your question and added any compile error messages you get and what compiler and platform you're using.

Comment: The only limitations on types in a structure are: (1) no instances of the structure being defined (but pointers to it are OK), which avoids infinitely big structures; (2) no variably-modified types; (3) no incomplete types except possibly for a 'flexible array member'.  The size is otherwise not limited explicitly; memory (for the computer) and memory (for the humans trying to process the structure) are the main limits otherwise.

Comment: Yes - what is your embedded target?

Comment: The compiler you use might have some really silly internal limitations, that really have nothing to do with C per se. (Like me, for example: I may read like a reasonable English-speaking person, but then and again me fail English. It's not a problem with English per se, just me. In compilers, such limitations tend to be very compiler specific, and may even vary from version to version.)

Comment: "Is there a size limit to how many members ...  a structure may contain?".  Yes.  That maximum limit is _at least_ 1023.  C11dr §5.2.4.1 1

Comment: Allocating a large object on the stack can cause stack overflow, particularly if she mentioned n a recursive function. More details would definitely help.

Comment: @Martin James. The target is PIC32MX460f512L using MPLAB X, MPLAB C compiler version 2.02 for PIC 32.

Comment: @newb7777 according to DS50001686J-page 20 (MPLAB XC Compiler user guide) it conforms C89. Therefore it should support 1023 members in structure and union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to standard, there is a limitation; but the limitation is much more than the size you mentioned here. C89 and C99 standard has the limit of 1023 structure members. See below text from the standard.

> **5.2.4.1 Translation limits**
>
> — 1023 members in a single structure or union

So looks like if your code is correct and limited to 1023 structure members the compiler you are using may have the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

There may indeed be a limit to the number of structure elements your compiler can handle for a single structure, but as MCG quoted from the C Standard, this limit must be at least 1023 for compliant compilers and most compilers have higher limits or no practical limits at all.

I suspect the problem is elsewhere:

- The Makefile for your project may have incomplete dependencies on the header file with the structure definitions: modules compiled with different definitions will be incompatible and produce undefined behavior. Remove all object files and recompile the project.
- Some assembly modules may rely on the original structure layout: changing the definition will only affect the recompiled C modules.
- Some library modules or OS system calls may rely on the original layout. Recompiling all libraries or even patching the OS may be required.
- Some functions may rely on the original layout and use casts to access some of the structures via another type. Changing the layout may break such code, which is brittle anyway as even changing compilers may produce similar problems.
- It is also possible that some of the type be multiply defined in different modules. This is poor and very error prone coding style as changing only one of the definitions will lead to undefined behavior when the object modules are linked together.